# Implicit conversion operator function from bool to enum class

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, enum-class

I have a function to change the state of an LED that takes in an enum argument with three possible values:

```
enum class Command { Off, On, Toggle };

void led(Command);
```

I'd like to be able to use the `led()` function with `bool` arguments: `led(true)` or `led(false)`.

I realize that I can overload the `void led(Command)` function with a `void led(bool)` but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary.

Specifically, I'm thinking I should be able to define an `operator` that provides an explicit conversion from `bool` to `Command`. I haven't been able to find the syntax for this. My current best guess is:

```
inline constexpr operator Command(bool on) { return on ? Command::On : Command::Off; }
```

But it seems the `operator` overloads can only be declared inside classes? I can see how I could do this with a full class instead of an `enum class`, but that seems heavy here.

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: That's the typical use case of function overloading, I doubt there's a better solution than `void led(bool)`

Comment: `enum class` only does so much.  If you want it to have behavior, you may want to use `class Command { public: enum Op { Off, On, Toggle}; /*...*/};` and then you have a place to add in member functions, conversion constructors, `explicit operator bool`, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

I think that function overloading was designed exactly for this need: same action, different input types. I'd change the method name though, usually a verb makes the action clearer and improves the code readability.

Something like:

```
void set_led(Command);
void set_led(bool on){
    if(on)
        return set_led(On);
    return set_led(Off);
}
```

Comment: Well, you wouldn't `return` the results of calling a void function, but otherwise yeah.

Comment: @Nathan that's perfectly legal in c++ (https://ideone.com/GroC04). Mat's just making it so they don't need an `else` statement or a separate line for the `return`.

Comment: Huh, didn't know that! Neat.

Comment: @Nathan Ehm, I didn't knew that either, that's captain-giraffe 's code! :-) Since he has several orders of magnitude more reputation than me, I have nothing to complain

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `set_led(on ? Command::On : Command::Off)`? Feels shorter and easier to read to me.

Comment: @CameronTacklind It is usually better write things once; if you like to write that in each call, well, you can, but I wouldn't be so happy if I were the code reviewer

Comment: @MatG I meant as the implementation of `set_led(bool on);`

Comment: @CameronTacklind Oh :-) As of the current function signature they are equivalent, it's just a matter of taste

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of `enum class` that you're using is to prevent comparisons directly to `int` (which `bool` has an implicit conversion to). So as long as you're using an `enum class`, there's no easy way to do this implicitly.

That said, you can take advantage of the fact that your `Off` is the first item of the enum (it'll convert to int `0`) and `On` is the second (which'll convert to `1`). Since this matches the implicit `bool` to `int` conversions for `false` and `true`, you can do:

```
led(Command(true));
led(Command(false));
```

See it in action: https://ideone.com/iWrc3s

---

Alternatively, you can switch to just an `enum` instead of an `enum class`, which will allow your `Command` to be implicitly converted to an `int`. Since `bool` also has an implicit conversion to `int`, you can change your `led()` method to take an `int` and then call it directly with:

```
led(true);
led(false);
```

See it in action: https://ideone.com/HF0cxI